# Como dispor imagens uma ao lado da outra com títulos abaixo em css?

Tags: html, css3, img

Gostaria de saber como dispor imagens lado a lado, com título/legenda embaixo. Usando CSS e a tag `<img>`, semelhante ao site da loja iTunes Store.

Comment: PFO seja mais objetivo, edite sua pergunta como o que vc já tem de código, alguma imagem do layout que pretende, se esta usando Bootstrap ou algum framework etc. Do jeito que vc perguntou não da para te responder precisamente.

Comment: Você tentou pelo menos? Tem um fonte base para isso?

Comment: Então, as imagens ficam ao lado, porém o texto não fica abaixo, e quando fica abaixo utilizando <br> a próxima imagem desce. Agora li as  respostas de outros usuários, e é isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. Muito obrigado á todos pelo tempo despendido e me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Muito Obrigado. Isso mesmo que eu buscava.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6759/bcd6c5c19f07cd76b023bd0716f3e4f88887c0f9v2_128.jpg"/>
    <span> Titulo da primeira imagem </span>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6759/bcd6c5c19f07cd76b023bd0716f3e4f88887c0f9v2_128.jpg"/>
    <span> Titulo da segunda imagem </span>
</div>

<style>
div.box {
 width: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6759/bcd6c5c19f07cd76b023bd0716f3e4f88887c0f9v2_128.jpg"/>
    <span> Titulo da primeira imagem </span>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6759/bcd6c5c19f07cd76b023bd0716f3e4f88887c0f9v2_128.jpg"/>
    <span> Titulo da segunda imagem </span>
</div>

<style>
div.box {
 width: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar **width** e **display: inline-block;** do CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6759/bcd6c5c19f07cd76b023bd0716f3e4f88887c0f9v2_128.jpg"/>
    <span> Titulo da primeira imagem </span>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://pm1.narvii.com/6759/bcd6c5c19f07cd76b023bd0716f3e4f88887c0f9v2_128.jpg"/>
    <span> Titulo da segunda imagem </span>
</div>

<style>
div.box {
 width: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for isso que você deseja:

```
.imagem{

  float: left;
  width: 50px;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="imagem">
   <img src="suaImagem1.jpg" title="escreva aqui seu titulo da imagem"/>
</div>

  <div class="imagem">
   <img src="suaimagem2.jpg" title="escreva aqui seu titulo da imagem"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se vc quiser ***não precisa*** usar `float` ou `display:inline-block`. Eu sugiro que use `FlexBox` porque é mais fácil ao meu ver de alinhar os itens.

Segue um exemplo usando o pseudo elemento `::after` para colocar a legenda, isso poupa algumas linhas de código. *(deixei um comentário no css)*

```css
.holder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.imagem {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.imagem::after {
  content: attr(data-title); /* estilo que coloco a legenda no lugar */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">

  <div class="imagem" data-title="legenda # 1">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/199/100" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="imagem" data-title="legenda # 2">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/201/100" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```